# Marginal density function question

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, multivariable-calculus

The question and answer is shown but I don't fully understand the answer for part a. Could someone please explain to me why the integral setup for the marginal density function of y1 is from y1 to 1, and not 0 to 1? And also the same thing for y2. Thank you
[image: Question]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a picture. Call the axis that we usually call the $x$-axis by the name $y_1$-axis, and the axis we usually call the $y$-axis the $y_2$-axis.

We need to identify the region where the density function lives. Note that the specifications say $0\le y_1\le y_2\le 1$. In terms of the more familiar names, we have $x\le y$. So we are **above** the line $y=x$. This line splits the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ into two triangles. The density function lives in the upper triangle.

Now to find the (marginal) density of $Y_1$, we have to "integrate out" $y_2$. So $y_2$ travels from $y_1$ to $1$.

To find the marginal density of $Y_2$, we have to integrate out $y_1$. We are in the upper triangle, so $y_1$ goes from $0$ to $y_2$.

Comment: hi Andre, I did draw the picture, but I am still struggling a little bit with understand the y1 to 1 part

Comment: All calculations with the density function $6(1-y_2)$ will have to be done over the upper triangle, because the density is $0$ elsewhere. So "$y$" goes from $x$ to $1$. We cannot have $y$ going from $0$ to $1$, because in the part from $y=0$ to $y=x$ the density function is $0$.

Comment: ah okay, thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. This stuff is very geometrical. Despite many years of teaching and using the material, I will not attack a problem without drawing a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Since you must integrate "out" the other variable essentially the question becomes what region do I integrate over. I think a nice way of integrating over joint probabilities is too look at joint probability as such 
$$f_{Y_{1},Y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})= f_{Y_{1}|Y_{2}}(y_{1}|y_{2})f_{Y_{2}}(y_{2})$$
Now why does looking at problem in this perspective help? It is because it helps make more clear how you would want integrate over the given support so for example to find marginal pdf of $Y_{1}$ integral would have some form as such
$$\int f_{Y_{1},Y_{2}}(y_{1},y_{2})dy_{1}=\int f_{Y_{1}|Y_{2}}(y_{1})f_{Y_{2}}(y_{2})dy_{1}$$
Now under this perspective we see that it resembles **law of total probability** some we must integrate over all possible values of $y_{2}$ which we see $y_{2}$ ranges from $y_{1}$ to $1$
$$\int_{y_{1}}^{1} f_{Y_{1}|Y_{2}}(y_{1}|y_{2})f_{Y_{2}}(y_{2})dy_{2}$$